# Django models not allowing one to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

Having a really tough time wrapping my head around creating this model set for Django.  Currently I am creating a site where a user can click the article to decide that he or she likes the article.  I have set up the models to include article, favorite articles, and user.   However, currently the way I have it set up is for it to only allow the user to have one favorite article, not two.  I am using the ForeignKey field and that is not working.  Here they are

```
from django.db import models
# users/models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
import uuid

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    url=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250, null =True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    git = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    homepage = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

class FavoriteArticles(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user', null=True)
    fav_title = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fav_title', null=True)
    reasons = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)
    favcategory = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favcategory', max_length=250, null =True)


    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.user
```

Comment: i didn't understand the line **...only allow the user to have one favorite article, not two.**. do you mean user(for eg: `lakerskill`) can only one favorite article(eg: `django`) not two (eg: `django` `c++`).

Comment: why you are creating two foreignkeys(ie `fav_title`, `favcategory`) to same model(ie: `Article`)?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? What do you expect it to do, and how is that different from what it does now?

Comment: also you're using the `related_name` parameter wrong. It defines the name for the _reverse_ relation on the remote model. e.g. for `user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='favorite_article', null=True)` you could then reference `self.request.user.favorite_article`.

Comment: also, usually using `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and `null=True` together is a mistake. What does it mean to have a `FavoriteArticles` with no user who fave'd it? And if you wanted to be able to keep fave counts accurate even when users are deleted, then why `CASCADE` deletes?

Comment: Should be able to select as many articles to favorite as they want too.  However, as it currently stands, all it's doing is allowing a user to have one favorite article.

Comment: You are adding fav_title and favcategory to Article with a foriegn key, which will show error as you will have two related_name. If you want to select category, then make a new class category, In Article add category with f.k and in Favorite Articles add Category class with f.k.